# I need to combine audio and video stream with fluent ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, pipe, fluent-ffmpeg

I need to take an input stream's audio and another stream's video and combine them with fluent-ffmpeg. I am using nodejs. Also, I need to pipe the output. Both of the inputs have video and audio, but I need to merge a stream's audio only, while doing the same with video on the other stream.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to use fluent-ffmpeg, if you have ffmpeg installed on your machine you can use [child-process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

```
const {exec} = require("child_process"); 
const command = "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4"
```

I got this command from [how to combine audio and video using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg)

```
exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
})
```

;

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. I had internet issues. The reason I used fluent-ffmpeg in the first place is that the inputs are streams. And I want to pipe the output to express as a response. I know how to do that, but I don't know the FFmpeg part. Also, both streams have audio and video as proposed above, so will it still work?

Comment: you can look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167893/pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-using-nodejs-stdout)

Comment: Yes, I did look at that answer before I came here, but it just says that stout is undefined. Also, what about the input? Can I just do something like `-i pipe:4` and will it work? I will try it again, but rigt now I am in the middle of class, so I will get back to you later

Comment: OK, so I tried the code in the link, and I get `dest.on is not a function`
Here is the link to the code and error:
https://pastebin.com/zMXDbeF7
error:
https://pastebin.com/pFiYTC42

Comment: you have to pass a write stream to pipe function, so `createWriteStream` to the `output.mp4`.

Comment: I will try it after class! I will mark your answer as correct if it works. Tanks! (that is a way of saying thank you.)

Comment: no problem, if you need anything else feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry, but when I try it, it runs without any errors, but the mp4 outputted is just blank. I also tried to hook it up with express, but it still downloaded a blank file. Sorry!

Comment: first check if you are actually output buffer array from `data.stdout.on("data",(chunck)=>{console.log(chunck);})` if there is any output then `res.contentType("video/mp4");  data.stdout.pipe(res); ` res is basically a writableStream .

Comment: I tried the code to log the chunks, but it just comes out blank. I think that ffmpeg is not outputting the output to the stream correctly, because when I change the `console.log()` in the chunk part to something like `console.log("chunk has happened");`, the string is not outputted at all. What could be the issue?

Comment: try this code `data.stderr.on("data",(err)=>{console.log(err.toString())});`  also remove the **out.mp4** from the command.
the prev code should return ffmpeg error

Comment: It finally worked! That command helped so much! I first got `no suitable format found for pipe:1`, so I added `-f mp4` to the command and got `muxer does not support non-seekable output`, so I did a bit of research and found out that I need to add `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` and it worked! Thank you so much! You have this 5th grader's respect!

Comment: no problem, if you need help with anything feel free to contact me on my email: ahmed.magdy.9611@gmail.com

Comment: @mrnoob do you mind sharing the snippet? I can't seem to get the piping working.